# How to get wicket's FeedbackMessages count

Tags: java, session, wicket

I am implementing AjaxRequestTarget.IListener. So my application automatically updates FeedbackPanel if there is any messages. And I would like to check if there is any messages my code:

```
        getAjaxRequestTargetListeners().add(new AjaxRequestTarget.IListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBeforeRespond(Map<String, Component> map,
                final AjaxRequestTarget target) {

            WebSession.get().getFeedbackMessages(); // Doesnt work
            target.getPage().getSession().getFeedbackMessages(); // Doesnt work
            target.getPage().visitChildren(IFeedback.class, new IVisitor<Component, Void>() {

                @Override
                public void component(Component component, IVisit<Void> visit) {
                    if (component.isVisibleInHierarchy()) {
                        target.add(component);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onAfterRespond(Map<String, Component> map, AjaxRequestTarget.IJavaScriptResponse response) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
target.getPage().visitChildren(FeedbackPanel.class, new IVisitor<FeedbackPanel, Void>() {
    @Override
    public void component(FeedbackPanel component, IVisit<Void> visit) {
        if (component.isVisibleInHierarchy() && component.anyMessage()) {
            target.add(component);
        }
    }
});
```

`component.getFeedbackMessages()` only returns messages added to that component. It doesn't take into account messages added to other components or session messages (i.e. `Session.get().error(...)`)

Here's what I use personally instead of a request listener:

```
public class CustomFeedbackPanel extends FencedFeedbackPanel {

    [...]

    @Override
    public void onEvent(IEvent<?> event) {
        // Always re-render the feedback panel input during ajax requests if it contains messages
        if (event.getPayload() instanceof AjaxRequestTarget && anyMessage()) {
            ((AjaxRequestTarget) event.getPayload()).add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware however that adding the feedback panel to an ajax request will erase previously displayed feedback messages on the client.

#### edit

I realize I did not answer the question asked in the question's title, but found another solution to the problem described.

So, to get the message count, there's the following protected method:
`List<FeedbackMessage> FeedbackPanel#getCurrentMessages()`

Comment: Looks pretty nice, I will try this one out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Wicket 6 that the storage of feedback messages has changed from Session to the components: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+6.0#MigrationtoWicket6.0-FeedbackStorageRefactoring

So if you use Wicket 6 you could check the number of feedback messages in the `IVisitor` where the component should implement `IFeedback` which has a method [`getCurrentMessages()`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/panel/FeedbackPanel.html#getCurrentMessages%28%29) that returns a `List` of feedback messages for the particular `IFeedback` component

Comment: Yes, I am using Wicket 6. So if I understood correctly I should check  `component.getFeedbackMessages()` but this one returns empty list too

Comment: So are you sure you have feedback messages?

Comment: Yep it shows it, I just want to check if there is any, there is no point always to add feedback panel to target

Answer (score 0):

in your base Web Application init() method, add an ajax listener will help:

```
protected void init() {  
super.init();  
//...  
this.getAjaxRequestTargetListeners().add(new AjaxRequestTarget.IListener() {   
public void onBeforeRespond(Map map, final AjaxRequestTarget target) {   
// DO THIS
 target.getPage().visitChildren(FeedbackPanel.class,
  new IVisitor<FeedbackPanel, Void>() {
    public void component(FeedbackPanel component, IVisit<Void> visit) {
        if (component.isVisibleInHierarchy() && component.anyMessage()) {
            target.add(component);

        }
                    visit.dontGoDeeper();
        }
    });
}
```